# CPLEX/OPL - constraint with boolean (optimisation model)

Tags: optimization, model, cplex, opl

I have an optimisation model which should allocate demand for 10 markets to 3 production sites. The production sites have their capacity and all demand has to be satisfied. I want to minimise the total costs.

However, I have also a parameter called approval which is saying if the production site can be used for a specific market = this is a boolean (1 if the site can produce, 0 If not). I struggle to define a constraint to include this approval in the model.

I have an objective function that minimizes the sum of the costs times quantity times approval, then I have 2 constraints to satisfy all demand and to not produce more than the production site's capacity. Now, I want to have a constraint to only considers costs of those production sites which have an approval = 1.

Anyone could please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Add the code that you have that does not work, then we comment on it

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.  It is customary to post code of *what you have tried* and what isn't working.  You will get better answers....  That said, I think I can point you in the right direction.

You need another index and a big-M.

in pseudocode:

You should be indexing your decision variable by both market & production source

```
Supply[p, m]   p ∈ {production sources}, m ∈ {markets}
```

this will allow you to write proper constraints.  And for your parameter regarding allowable p-m pairs, you can then simply set up a similar double-indexed parameter.

```
Allowable[p, m] ∈ {binary}
```

And then use a big-M constraint to clamp any production to zero for "illegal" pairings.

```
Supply[p, m] <= Allowable[p, m] * M
```

If any of those concepts are new to you, there are many examples/resources online or in a Linear Programming text.